# Is the TMDS intended for long distance transmission?

Tags: lvds

The TMDS Transition-minimized differential signaling is similar to LVDS but not identical. I have a few questions about it:

1. Why does it use current mode logic instead of the ubiquitous voltage mode signal?
2. Is it intended for use on PCB for IC-IC transmission or across distances between systems via cables?
3. What was the limitation of LVDS that prompted creation of TMDS?

Comment: Serial communication schemes are almost universally (for newer systems) current mode (including LVDS which is defined as 3.5mA into a nominal 100 ohms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, TMDS is intended for long distances, but it depends if you consider roughly 10 meters as long.

Longer answer, the two terms are not exactly comparable.

TMDS is a special kind of 8b/10b line code, a data coding method, which is specified to be sent using CML PHY layer, while LVDS is strictly a PHY layer that can be used to send any data with or without line coding.

1. Speed. CML (used commonly on TMDS interfaces) allows for faster data rates than LVDS.
2. Both. For example links between high speed chips can use CML for speed, and also your displays connected with DVI and HDMI use TMDS with CML over the video cables.
3. Same as 1, speed.

Comment: I don't come across current mode stuff often. I work with FPGAs and sometimes Microcontrollers. What could be the reason for this? I see FPGA I/Os being quite flexible but never current mode, they always have I/O standards like CMOS, TTL e.t.c of which none is current mode logic as far as I am aware.

Comment: Larger application processors have direct HDMI output and larger FPGAs have high speed pins that can be set to CML mode for connecting to high speed CML chips. A low end FPGA or standard MCU would not have CML IO because the speed is not needed.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 If you have control over the board design, LVDS to and from CML translations only take a few components. This of course won't give you the speed advantages of CML, but if your sink requires it (e.g. a HDMI monitor), it's trivial to implement.